# Python str.format() --- passing in list, outputting list

Tags: python, string, list, string-formatting

I haven't used str.format() much before and am wondering how to pass in list values and retrieve a list output with these values passed in.

i.e.

```
listex = range(0, 101, 25)
baseurl = "https://thisisan{0}example.com".format(*listex)
```

I'd like a list output like `["https://thisisan0example.com", "https://thisisan25example.com", "https://thisisan50example.com", etc etc]`

but with my current code above, I'm only getting `"https://thisisan0example.com"` when I run `print baseurl`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot get your output as shown using a single format. You can use a list-comp

```
>>> listex = range(0, 101, 25)
>>> ["https://thisisan{}example.com".format(i) for i in listex]
['https://thisisan0example.com', 'https://thisisan25example.com', 'https://thisisan50example.com', 'https://thisisan75example.com', 'https://thisisan100example.com']
```

You can use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) here (if you are using Py3, wrap a `list` call),

```
>>> map("https://thisisan{}example.com".format,listex)
['https://thisisan0example.com', 'https://thisisan25example.com', 'https://thisisan50example.com', 'https://thisisan75example.com', 'https://thisisan100example.com']
```

This can then be stored in your variable `baseurl` as

```
baseurl = map("https://thisisan{}example.com".format,listex)
```

The speed comparision can be done using `timeit`

```
$ python -m timeit 'listex = range(0, 101, 25);["https://thisisan{}example.com".format(i) for i in listex]'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.73 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit 'listex = range(0, 101, 25);map("https://thisisan{}example.com".format,listex)'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.36 usec per loop
```

As you can see, the `map` is faster here (Python2) as there is no involvement of a `lambda`

Comment: fetch the point.. came with the same.. Hmm.. For the first time i see, Martjin misunderstood a question.. This proves that he is a human :-)

Comment: first time i've seen Martjin stumble too :)

Answer (score 2):

You can list comp this:

```
baseurl = ["https://thisisan{0}example.com".format(x) for x in listex]
```

This essentially loops through `listex` and builds `baseurl` with a unique version of the given string for each element.

Answer (score 2):

**Method-1: Using map and lambda:**

```
baseurl = map(lambda x: "https://thisisan{0}example.com".format(x), listex)
['https://thisisan0example.com',
 'https://thisisan25example.com',
 'https://thisisan50example.com',
 'https://thisisan75example.com',
 'https://thisisan100example.com']
```

Here, `map()` will apply the `lambda`  function to each element of `listex` and return a list with the elements changed by the `lambda` function.

**Method-2: Using List comprehension:**

```
baseurl = ["https://thisisan{0}example.com".format(item) for item in listex]
['https://thisisan0example.com',
 'https://thisisan25example.com',
 'https://thisisan50example.com',
 'https://thisisan75example.com',
 'https://thisisan100example.com']
```

Here, we use list comprehension to achieve the desired result.